Azure Pipeline not triggered by changes to other than self repository
I have two repositories and both are in same project of ADO:
one is at the top level (It also include pipeline yaml), and the other is defined as a submodule. I want to trigger a pipeline whenever an update is pushed to either the main repository or any of the repositories declared as resources(submodule mentioned here).
I tried below code but it only trigger on changes in self or if i run manually.
trigger: 
- main

pool:
  name: 'myselfhostedagent'

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: sub_repo
    type: git
    name: test/sub_repo
    ref: master
    trigger:
    - master

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: sub_repo
- script: |
      echo $(Build.Repository.Name)
      echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
      dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

Troubleshooting:

I defined self trigger to none but no success
I created pipeline in sub_repo and it getting trigger properly
As per docs
"If a change to any other repository resource triggers the pipeline, then the latest version of YAML from the default branch of self repository is used."
I verified that my self repo has defined main as default branch.
After manual run if i check changes section of last pipeline run instance it shows both current pipeline and sub_repo changes

Any tips to resolve this or any way to verify from logs that as soon as i do push in sub_repo how AzureDevOps handle it.
Edit1:  In response to @Alvin Zhao


if the above YAML contents are from the pipeline.yml in main branch of the TopRepo?


Yes its from TopRepo


And for the sub_repo resource, the actual project name is test and the actual repo name is sub_repo?


Project name is test and i modified repo name for asking question.


What is the default branch of sub_repo by the way.


For TopRepo default branch is main, For sub_repo its master


Please double check the Trigger settings in pipeline WEB UI if the option to Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here was checked


It was not checked i did now, but results are same no success


My pipeline based on your description could be triggered by the self TopRepo and the sub_repo resource. It worked no matther the sub_repo was added as the submodule of TopRepo or not. May I know if the above YAML contents are from the pipeline.yml in main branch of the TopRepo?

And for the sub_repo resource, the actual project name is test and the actual repo name is sub_repo?

What is the default branch of sub_repo by the way.

In addition, Please double check the Trigger settings in pipeline WEB UI if the option to Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here was checked

@AlvinZhao-MSFT Please find respones i put as Edit1.

Hi @ImranRazaKhan, Please don't check that option; it will disable the resource trigger in YAML pipeline

Based on your update the pipeline should be able to get triggered by the commit pushed tomain branch of self and the master branch of the sub_repo. I will share some screenshots of my working pipeline in the answer section shortly for your to check and compare.

Based on the description, my pipeline referencing the azure-pipelines.yml in the main branch of self TopRepo was able to get trigged by the commits pushed to the main branch of TopRepo and to the master branch of sub_repo in test project.
Here is the sample for your reference to check and compare.



Now my pipeline is running fine. The problem wasn't with the code; I had to recreate my pipeline. My main branch wasn't set as the default initially, and after creating the pipeline, I made it the default. I think this caused some issues. I'm accepting your answer as it helped me focus on other aspects.

Thank you for your update. If you old pipeline is not removed, you may try to change the pipeline default branch for a test. I updated the answer with another screenshot. Appreciate your time and sharing, which I believe will help others with similar concerns. Happy weekend.

Unfortunatly i deleted that, Thanks for additional screenshot, it will definitly help community.
